# Is there a NoSQL, document based, system out there that will let concurrent updates?

Tags: nosql

I'm wondering if there is a document based NoSQL server that will allow concurrent updates to the same system without clobbering the document. For example, here is a JSON document thats stored:

```
{
  foo: 'bar',
  goo: 'nar'
}
```

If two people attempt to save updates person A:

```
{
  foo: 'bar red',
  goo: 'nar'
}
```

and person B:

```
{
  foo: 'bar',
  goo: 'nar green'
}
```

The system would save an un-clobbered version:

```
{
  foo: 'bar red',
  goo: 'nar green'
}
```

A more complex example would be something like the following, where each person could edit foo and goo, yet still not be clobbered.

```
{
  items: [{foo:'bar'}, {goo:'nar'}]
}
```

into:

```
{
  items: [{foo:'bar red'}, {goo:'nar green'}]
}
```

Comment: Many database systems have operations which update only specific fields while not touching the others. Would that fulfill your requirement? Or would you need the database to support checking automatically which fields are unchanged *since that user received their copy* and behave differently when the field was changed by another connection in the meantime?

Comment: @Philipp - failing the update when in conflict would be OK. Being notified what fields were in conflict would be ideal.